# Two datetime formatting strings in one vector

Tags: datetime, format

i have a large structure dataset.
each field in the structure is a XXXX*4 cell. the XXXX are because they are not constant in size. the first column is datetime.
the problem is that part of the vector is in the format of: '1/9/2015 00:00:00' that is dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss
while the other part is in the format of '1/9/2015 00:00' that is dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm.
this change can happen more then once in each date vector.
is there any way to call the datetime function with two format types? or a general one that covers both of these?

for lack of a better option i would scan each row, and fix it, but it would take  a lot of time. hope someone can help... thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

well, i just made a for loop, and wrote this inside:

```
s=fieldnames(DataSet);

for i=1:length(fieldnames(DataSet))
  for j=2:(length(DataSet.(s{i})))

    if length(DataSet.(s{i}){j,1})>=17
        DataSet.(s{i}){j,1}=DataSet.(s{i}){j,1}(1:(length(DataSet.(s{i}){j,1})-3));
    end

 end
end
```

it worked. actually pretty fast, only took 7 seconds (i was a bit surprised)
notice it only works to change from 'dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss' to 'dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm'.
but i guess you can manipulate it to adjust most types.